# Veins : multiple WSMs for different purpose

Tags: omnet++, veins

I want to send two WSMs, one on regular intervals to enable a vehicle (V1) receive the information about vehicle behind them (V2) from the vehicle (V3), which is behind V2. 
The second WSM is only sent out in certain cases (as a warning message) and as soon as vehicles receive the warning WSM, I want them to change the lane.

Question is: how can I implement two WSM actions independent from each other? Can I at all use multiple WSMs for this purpose or shall I define a new message type for it?

Comment: My recommendation is to define a new message type for each use

Comment: By defining a new message, we are talking about a whole new msg file with required fields or can we do it in an easier manner?

Comment: You can, of course copy and modify and existing .msg file. This would be the easiest solution